# Find multiple instances with regex

Tags: regex

I am currently in a bit of a pickle with JS Regex. From the following code, we need to extract the content inside the `div` or `span`:

```
<span class="code">
    !(true ^ false)
</span>

<span class="code">
    (true ^ false)
</span>
```

So we need to match both `!(true ^ false)` and `(true ^ false)`

I came up with the following regex: `/<(div|span) class="code">([\s\S]+)<\/(div|span)>/im`. This works when there is only one `div` or `span` in the to be matched text. However, in the situation outlined above, the match is:

```
    ! (true ^ false)
</span>

<span class="code">
    !(true ^ false)
```

So basically it only takes the opening and the ending `tag`. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Why not using a parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is to put a `?` behind your `+` to make the match non-greedy and then add the `g` modifier to continue searching after the first match:

```
<(div|span) class="code">\s*([\s\S]+?)<\/(div|span)>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT3dB9/1)

Comment: Really? I spent one and a half hour on this and the solution is to add a "?".. Pff I hate coding :P

Comment: @Diederik Well, when it comes to regular expressions, the tiniest of detail can make a huge difference. Take it as a learning experience ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Should fix it by matching `<div>` with `</div>`  and `<span>` with `</span>` and making regex lazy using `?`

**Regex:** `<(div|span) class="code">([\s\S]+?)<\/\1>`

**Explanation:**

- Matching  `<div>` with `</div>` should be done by using back-referencing for first captured group using `\1`.
- Made regex to match minimum tags using `?`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV3bR5/1)**